# Multiple table modification(same table has been used in that function) inside the Postgresql function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, ddl

```
create or replace function report(IN rows_count numeric DEFAULT 1000,
                                  OUT out_rc_type rc_type)
  RETURNS rc_type 
AS 
DECLARE 
BEGIN   
    PERFORM ddl_exec_pkg.ddl_execute ( 'ALTER TABLE REPORT_UI DROP CONSTRAINT REPORT_ID'); 
    PERFORM ddl_exec_pkg.ddl_execute ( 'ALTER TABLE REPORT_ALL_UI DROP CONSTRAINT REPORT_ID'); 
    INSERT INTO
    REPORT_UI (SELECT * FROM GE_REPORT);     
    PERFORM ddl_exec_pkg.ddl_execute ('ALTER TABLE REPORT_UI ADD  CONSTRAINT REPORT_ID CHECK (1 = 1)'); 
    PERFORM ddl_exec_pkg.ddl_execute ('ALTER TABLE REPORT_ALL_UI ADD CONSTRAINT REPORT_ID CHECK (1 = 1)');   
END;
```

When in run the above code I am getting below error:

> ERROR:   cannot ALTER TABLE "REPORT_UI "

because it is being used by active queries in this session CONTEXT:

```
SQL statement "ALTER TABLE REPORT_UI ADD  
    CONSTRAINT REPORT_ID    CHECK (1 = 1)"
```

Comment: There's a typo in your code: I don't think you should use `fucntion` there. What about reading the error message - doesn't that provide additional background for the problem?

Comment: What is `ddl_exec_pkg`? Is this regular PostgreSQL or some modified fork? Please tag appropriately.

Comment: Why are you removing the constraints just to add them back after you inserted the data? I doubt if that improves performance in any way especially with a check constraint which isn't really that expensive during an insert (assuming you real constraint actually makes sense because `check (1=1)`  is useless)

Comment: Additionally: are you aware that you don't really need to call a function to run DDL in Postgres? You can embedd the ALTER TABLE statements directly into the function

Comment: i am removing the constraint to insert the duplicate records in unique key column and updating the null in the not null column. when I try to alter the table its not allow me to do that.

Comment: Also tried to use ALTER TABLE  directly in that function but its not working